# Facebook OAuth Login Error Without "www" in URL

Tags: asp.net, facebook-oauth

I'm facing a problem in Facebook Oauth Login.

When trying to login with Facebook (OpenAuth) in my website, I have encountered with this error.

- **Condition 1:** If i try to Login with URL [www.medimart.com.np/sf/sfLogin.aspx](http://www.medimart.com.np/sf/sfLogin.aspx) . Login is successful and everything is working fine.
- **Condition 2:** But if i try to Login with URL [medimart.com.np/sf/sfLogin.aspx](http://medimart.com.np/sf/sfLogin.aspx).
  Login is failed and I get Error Message:

  > "message": "Can't Load URL: The domain of this URL isn't included in the app's domains. To be able to load this URL, add all domains and subdomains of your app to the App Domains field in your app settings."

How can i fix this issue?

[image: setting Image]
[image: Facebook Login Page Setting]

Comment: shouldn't you have a unique URL that represents your app? like redirecting www traffic to non-www or vice versa?

Comment: yes .. that is what i'm looking for... How can i achieve that?

Comment: install URL rewrite module in IIS, follow [this](https://madskristensen.net/blog/url-rewrite-and-the-www-subdomain) short post for direct config in web.config file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Facebook always check for the **WWW** domain. So make sure that **www.medimart.com.np** is working on your browser.

---

You have to edit your **hosts** file here:

```
C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
```

And add below lines:

```
127.0.0.1 medimart.com.np
127.0.0.1 www.medimart.com.np
```

See How to [Modify your hosts file](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/).

---

A [link](https://madskristensen.net/blog/url-rewrite-and-the-www-subdomain) shared from the *Ermir* 's comment.

> There are two camps on the subject of the www subdomain. One believe it should be enforced (www.yes-www.org) and the other (no-www.org) that it should be removed. They are both right.
>
> **What's important is that there is only a single canonical address to your website – with or without www.**
>
> Your server needs to have the [URL Rewrite module](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) installed. Chances are that it does already. Azure Websites does and so does all of my other hosting providers.

Use below rule for the domain **without WWW**:

```
<rule name="Remove WWW" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="*://www.*" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Use below rule for the domain **with WWW**:

```
<rule name="Enforce WWW" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{CACHE_URL}" pattern="^(.+)://(?!www)(.*)" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}://www.{C:2}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Now you can add above rule in web.config file:

```
<system.webServer>
  <rewrite>
    <rules>
      <!-- Add your rules here -->
    </rules>
  </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: I need to fix this in such a way that a customer(who can be any body) can create an account using Facebook and doesn't get an error like above despite even when he/she uses "medimart.com.np"

Comment: then the domain `www.medimart.com.np` is correct for your customers.

Answer (score 0):

As @AsifAli72090 suggested,  this is have i have learned.

**"Facebook always check for the WWW domain."**

So there must be "www" in your domain while trying to Login with your facebook account. Redirect "yourdomain.com" to "www.yourdomain.com". So I ended up add this code in my web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect domain.com to www" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url=".*" />
        <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^yourdomain.com$" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.yourdomain.com/{R:0}" />
    </rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```